# When does the kernel decide to have multiple vnode entries for a single file?

Tags: c, file-descriptor

I found this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353461/open-what-happens-if-i-open-twice-the-same-file) and have several follow up questions.

```
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
  // have kernel open two connection to file alphabet.txt which contains letters from a to z
  int fd1 = open("alphabet.txt",O_RDONLY);
  int fd2 = open("alphabet.txt",O_RDONLY);


  // read a char & write it to stdout alternately from connections fs1 & fd2
  while(1)
  {
    char c;
    if (read(fd1,&c,1) != 1) break;
    write(1,&c,1);
    if (read(fd2,&c,1) != 1) break;
    write(1,&c,1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

1. If I open the same file (under the same directory) independently in two processes, will it create two vnode entries? Or it depends on the OS?

```
  // PID 1
  int fd1 = open("alphabet.txt",O_RDONLY);
  // PID 2
  int fd2 = open("alphabet.txt",O_RDONLY);
```

2. How does `read()` know where is the file? Does C first ask for the vnode entry of `fd1` and return the address of it?
3. Following 2., does `read()` create new vnode entry or is it using the same one?

Comment: "If I open the same file (under the same directory) independently in two processes, will it create two vnode entries? Or it depends on the OS?"  The existence of vnodes (at all) depends on the OS.

Answer (score 0):

1. Opening the same file in two processes does not create two `vnode`
   entries. The `vnode` is a data structure in the
   kernel that represents a file. If you open the same file twice,
   either within the same process or in two different processes, you
   get two different file descriptors. These file descriptors are
   independent of each other, but they both point to the same `vnode`.
2. The `read()` function knows the location of the file through the file
   descriptor. When you call `open()`, the operating system returns a
   file descriptor, which is an integer. This file descriptor is an
   index into an array in the kernel called the file descriptor table.
   This table contains the information about all open files, including
   the `vnode` of the file. So when `read()` is called with a file
   descriptor, it looks up the file descriptor table to find the `vnode`
   and thus the location of the file.
3. The `read()` function does not create a new `vnode` entry. The `vnode` is
   created when the file is first opened, and subsequent calls to
   `open()` on the same file will return a new file descriptor pointing
   to the same `vnode`. The `read()` function only reads data from the
   file, it does not change the `vnode` or the file descriptor table.

Answer (score 0):

When you `open(2)` a file, the kernel creates a new file table entry, which includes a file pointer to know where the next `read(2)`/`write(2)` will go.

When you `dup(2)` a file, the second descriptor points to the same file table entry, so they share the same descriptor, and the reads/writes serialize, based on the same pointer.

This is not only a linux characteristici, it is incorporated to posix and belongs to the original UNIX design.  When a process `fork(2)`s, the descriptors are `dup(2)`ed and so parent and child share the same descriptors and file pointers.

The per process file descriptor table has only file entry pointers, while the file entry has the file open flags, the file pointer and a reference to the inode (which is unique in the kernel per file)

This makes that two processes that, independently open the same file, to have different file pointers, while a parent process that passes an open file to a child proces, actually share de file pointer, because the file descriptor has been `dup()`ed, instead.

When I was first studying the system, I learned about a system call (that I don't remember it's name now) similar to `dup(2)` but actually reopening the file descriptor (and so, obtaining a different pointer) the idea of it is to have a completely independent opened file (as if I had opened it) but using as input, not the filename (that, because of redirections, could be unknown to the process) I don't remember the name of that system call (I thought it was something like `int reopen(int fd, int open_flags);`  but I don't remember the name.  If somebody knows about it, please drop me a comment on that.